# HAproxy backend 503 connection refused over VPN

Tags: vpn, haproxy

I have a simple setup for HAProxy to a back-end server available over an IPSec VPN. When I connect directly to the back-end server using `Curl`, the requests goes through successfully, but when I use HAProxy to the same back-end, over the VPN, the request is dropped with a 503 ERROR. From the logs, it seems the connection is being aborted prematurely, but I cannot decipher why. Also, both requests work when I use remote servers available over the Internet as back-ends, where a VPN is not involved. Am I missing a specific config or something for HAProxy over a VPN?

Note: I have set no health check on purpose for the back-end

HAProxy config:

```
defaults
mode                    http
# option                httplog
log                     global      #use log set in the global config
log-format              \"[Lo:%ci/%cp; Re:%si/%sp] [Proxy - %bi:%bp/%fi:%fp] [%tr] %ft %b/%s %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta %ST %B %CC %CS %tsc %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq %hr %hs %{+Q}r\"
option dontlognull
option http-keep-alive
option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
option                  redispatch
retries                 2
timeout http-request    10s     #maximum allowed time to wait for a complete HTTP request 
timeout queue           10s     #maximum time to wait in the queue for a connection slot to be free 
timeout connect         5s      #maximum time to wait for a connection attempt to a server to succeed 
timeout client          5s      #minimum time for inactivity on client side 
timeout server          5s      #maximum inactivity time on the server side 
timeout http-keep-alive     30s     #maximum allowed time to wait for a new HTTP request to appear 
timeout check           10s 
maxconn                 5000

##----------------------------------------------------- 
## API Requests 
##----------------------------------------------------- 
## frontend to proxy HTTP callbacks coming from App servers to VPN Server
frontend api_requests 
    mode                http
    bind                10.132.2.2:80
    bind                127.0.0.1:80
    default_backend     testbed

## backend to proxy HTTP requests from App Servers to VPN Server
backend testbed
    balance     roundrobin
    server      broker  196.XXX.YYY.136:80
```

Entry captured on traffic log for failed attempt over VPN :

```
May 30 09:15:10 localhost haproxy[22844]: [Lo:127.0.0.1/56046; Re:196.XXX.YYY.136/80] [Proxy - :0/127.0.0.1:80] [30/May/2019:09:15:10.285] api_requests testbed/broker 0/0/-1/-1/0 503 212 - - SC-- 1/1/0/0/2 0/0 "POST /request HTTP/1.1"
```

What could be the issue causing a `Curl` request to be accepted but a proxy request by HAProxy to be dropped specifically for a VPN connection? Anyone faced a similar issue before?

Comment: And Nginx worked right off the bat. For now, am using that till this issue is resolved

Comment: Can you check if the server is actually green on a statistics page. also notice if your request changing the counters on the statistics page to this server.
If it is not green try to set health state to UP by force with socat API.

set server <backend>/<server> health up

Comment: @BohdanBiehov the remote server is a public service, accessible via others too anytime, so I can confirm it is always available, that's why I saw no need to put the health check. Also, on the health check, I actually tried enabling it, but the communication between HAProxy and the remote server on the other end of the VPN never occurs, thus I cannot even set a health check even if I wanted to. But weirdly, I can set a health check for any other server not on the VPN

Comment: the reason I asked about checking it on statistics page is to ensure communication from haproxy(the process) to your server is alive. Having your service available on public or reachable with curl proves that the server is up and runing and haproxy VM can reach it but it doesn't mean it is considered healthy from haproxy perspective. By the way curl works from haproxy VM ? Anyhow seems like you do have a problem with connection from haproxy to your server. I would debug it in following way: set 'mode tcp', add 'check'. check statistics. collect network capture with tcpdump.

Comment: @BohdanBiehov yes, curl works from the same VM HAProxy is installed to the same endpoint.